# Show triangle inequality in the metric.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let be $d:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a function such that $$a)d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$$ $$b)d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(z,y)$$

Prove that $d$ is a metric.

First, let be $z=x$, then $$0\leq d(x,y)+d(x,y)\to d(x,y)\geq 0$$
So, $d(x,y)\geq 0$. Second, let be $x=y$, then $$d(x,z)\leq d(y,x)+d(z,x)=d(z,x)$$
But, I don't know how prove that $d(z,x)\leq d(x,z)$. And the finally condition for metric is by hypothesis.

Comment: You have an error in the beginning of your reasoning. If $z=y$, then you should have $d(x,y) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,y)$. To get what you concluded, try setting $z=x$.

Comment: You can just switch $x$ and $z$ in the argument.

Comment: Using your definition, you can derive both $d(x,z) - d(z,x) \leq 0$ and $d(z,x) - d(x,z) \leq 0$ by simply swapping $x$ and $z$.

Comment: can you give a proper title to this question?

Comment: Tell me that title is more appropriate @Pinocchio

Comment: no, you think about it. It should be obvious its too generic to be helpful for searches. Prove that is a metric? prove what is a metric? Don't you know the definition? Just give a specific title. I should have a general idea what ur question is about without having to read it and I dont with ur current title. @pabloperez

Comment: You're liar @Pinocchio xD, I changed the title, thanks

Comment: ur welcome ;) glad it helped! :)

Comment: The triangle inequality is actually given as condition b). What you're trying to show is that your function is symmetric ($d(x,z)=d(z,x)$ for all $x$ and $z$).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my previous helpless answer.

As commented, swap $x$ and $z$ in Eq.(b) first:
$$
d(z,x)\ \leq\ d(z,y)+d(x,y)
$$
Let $y=z$, then
$$
d(z,x)\ \leq\ d(z,z)+d(x,z)\ =\ d(x,z)
$$
Due to 
$
d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$, now $d(z,z)=0$ thus $d(z,x) \leq\ d(x,z)$

Comment: No, it was not an error. If $x=y$ then you can write either $x$ or $y$ wherever either of those symbols should appear. It makes no difference which you write, because they're equal.

Comment: Is the same @dainy

Comment: @pabloperez, take a look at the new content now. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, Thanks for all! @Dainy